# Is it possible to reshape data in R such that two rows are split under one new column?

Tags: r

Apologies if the question is slightly cryptic, I was struggling to word it so did as best I could.

I have a data frame (or data table) with some basic task information;

```
names<-c('Neil','Neil', 'Neil', 'Andrew')
task<-c("Task 1","Task 1", "Task 2", "Task 3")
date<-c("2016-01-01","2016-02-01", "2016-01-15", "2016-01-01")
duration<-c(7, 7, 7, 7)
count<-c(1,2,1,1)
testLong<-data.frame(names,task,date,duration,count,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

This returns

```
+------------------------------------------------+
|   names   |task   |date       |duration |count |
+------------------------------------------------+
| 1:   Neil |Task 1 |2016-01-01 |       7 |    1 |
| 2:   Neil |Task 1 |2016-02-01 |       7 |    2 |
| 3:   Neil |Task 2 |2016-01-15 |       7 |    1 |
| 4: Andrew |Task 3 |2016-01-01 |       7 |    1 |
+------------------------------------------------+
```

If would like to reshape this data so that the count column becomes a column header over the date and duration fields with a target output of;

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|   names   |task   | 1                 |2                    |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1:   Neil |Task 1| 2016-01-01  |     7|2016-02-01  |      7 |
| 2:   Neil |Task 2| 2016-01-15  |     7|NA          |      NA|
| 3: Andrew |Task 3| 2016-01-01  |     7|NA          |      NA|
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I have tried tidyr (spread) and dcast but can't get quite what I am looking for.

I am thinking of some convoluted method of subsetting based on the name and task creating a vector of dates and durations which I can then bind back on but hope there is a better way that I simply can't find.

Many Thanks

Comment: This is a common reshape of long to wide. R does not support having empty columns though, so your exact format is impossible in my book.

Answer (score 1):

`reshape` to the rescue:

```
reshape(testLong, idvar=c("names","task"), timevar="count", direction="wide")

#   names   task     date.1 duration.1     date.2 duration.2
#1   Neil Task 1 2016-01-01          7 2016-02-01          7
#3   Neil Task 2 2016-01-15          7       <NA>         NA
#4 Andrew Task 3 2016-01-01          7       <NA>         NA
```